# Body pin of a MOSFET

Tags: power, power-electronics, powermosfet, bms

[image]

I am designing a BMS. I am controlling the power distribution unit of BMS with MOSFET i.e. charge MOSFET and discharge MOSFET. The reason to use charge and discharge MOSFETs is because MOSFET is a unidirectional current control device. Now if I can find a MOSFET whose body pin is given externally like a gate pin and I could then select where the body of the MOSFET will connect (source or drain, wherever it connects it will be source) thus changing the body diodes direction of the MOSFET, then I could use only 1 MOSFET and not charge and discharge MOSFETs separately. While discharging current the MOSFETs body diode's direction will be in one way and while charging it will be in the other way.

I understand such a thing might not be possible but if someone from VLSI/chip level's point of view could explain then thank you.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: why a body pin of a mosfet cant be given externally?

Comment: This answer explains why the body pin of a MOSFET isn't given externally: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/137186/65892